# How to discard unwanted tokens

Tags: java, loops, iterator, token

I made this token iterator class that scans an input line by each character and creates `String`s. I am able to make the class read all the tokens and separate them, but I cannot get it to remove all the invalid/unwanted tokens in an input.

I tried doing something with `character.toString(counter)` so those characters are made into a string and then wrote if statements that when the token is not "not", "true" , "false" or "and" then discard it and go on to the next token.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Tokiter implements Iterator<String>{
    private char counter = 0;
    //input line to be tokenized
    private String line;

    // the next Token, null if no next Token
    private String nextToken;

        // implement
    public TokIter(String line){
        this.line = line;
    }


    @Override
    // implement
    public boolean hasNext() {

        if (counter >= line.length())
            return false;
        else if (line.charAt(counter) == ' ')
        {
            counter++;
            return hasNext();
        }

        else
            return true;
    }


    @Override
    //implement
    public String next() {
        String s = "";
        if (!hasNext())
        {
    //          System.out.println("Null");
            return null;
        }
        else if( line.charAt(counter) == ('('))
        {
    //          System.out.println("Token");
            s += line.charAt(counter);
            counter++;
            return s;
        }
        else if( line.charAt(counter) == (')'))
        {   
    //          System.out.println("Token");
            s += line.charAt(counter);
            counter++;
            return s;
        }
        else
            s += line.charAt(counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter >= line.length()){
            return s;
        }
        while (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(counter)))
        {
            s += line.charAt(counter);
            counter++;
            if (counter >= line.length()){
                return s;
            }


        }
        return s;
    }   


    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

        // provided
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String line;
        // you can play with other inputs on the command line
        if(args.length>0)
            line = args[0];
        // or do the standard test
        else
            line = " not random (true or false) ** whatever ";
        System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
        Tokiter tokIt = new Tokiter(line);
        while(tokIt.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

So for example when the program runs the input line `not random (true or false) ** whatever` the output will be:

```
line: [  not random (true or false) ** whatever  ]    
next token: [not]    
next token: [(]    
next token: [true]    
next token: [or]    
next token: [false]    
next token: [)]
```

Comment: do you get any error? or you think you just have logical error?

Comment: Do you know that this entire class can be replaced by oneliner? [regexp + split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)?

Comment: Note that if you are going to drop tokens that are not "correct", your `hasNext()` as it is now is going to violate the `Iterator` contract, as it will return `true` for that `**`, while you will not be returning it. Also, returning `null` from `next()` is also a violation of the contract - you are supposed to throw `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Currently your class has two responsibilities: tokenizing the input and iterating over those tokens. You may find that by separating those two things into two classes that the implementation is easier (and if you store the tokens in an existing Java collection class you won't even need to implement `Iterator` yourself).

Comment: yeah i know it could be done better and simpler but I have to do it this way for now. it was mentioned that my hasNext() would violate the iterator contract. In my hasNext(), I did the case where if it was a space then to just skip it and go on to the next token, so would I have to add the case where if it is an invalid token. do the same thing and just go to the next token?